# What GPU can I put in my Mac Pro 5,1?

Tags: hardware, mac-pro, gpu

I have Mac Pro 5,1 (Mid-2010) and I want to upgrade it's GPU to increase the performance of Windows under Bootcamp. I do not care about GPU power in OSX.

Which GPUs are supported in OS X/macOS ? (I also do not care about boot screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got one of those Macs, I put an AMD RX 480 in mine, as you can use it in both MacOS and windows. (MacOS requires 10 minutes of tinkering to get it fully working).

As of now, the "Pascal" Architecture of Nvidia GPUs aren’t supported in MacOS, and there hasn’t been any announcements to say there will be.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has an "official" [list of graphics cards that are compatible with the Mac Pros](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201805)  (Mid 2010).

The ones specific to the 5,1 are:

> #### Mac Pro (Mid 2010) and Mac Pro (Mid 2012)
>
> - ATI Radeon HD 5770
> - ATI Radeon HD 5870

Now, according to [EveryMac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/faq/mac-pro-default-graphics-cards-dvi-dual-link-mini-displayport.html), there are several more adapters that are compatible:

- NVIDIA Quadro FX 4800
- NVIDIA Quadro 4000
- AMD Sapphire Radeon HD 7950*
- EVGA GeForce GTX 680
- PNY NVIDIA Quadro K5000

> Please note that the Sapphire Radeon HD 7950 only is compatible with the Mid-2010 and Mid-2012 Mac Pro models. The other four video cards above are compatible with the Early 2008 and Early 2009 as well as the Mid-2010 and Mid-2012 Mac Pro models.

Personally, I have used the  [AMD Sapphire Radeon HD 7950](http://radnex.us/ATI_Saphire_Radeon_HD_7950) because it wasn't just compatible with OS X (10.7+), but Windows Vista (which meant it worked in 7 and should work in [Windows 10](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows%2010%20-%2064)) and FreeBSD as well.

I am currently refurbing a Mid-2012 Mac Pro (side project) and I fully intend to put this exact card in the mix.

Comment: Beyond this, almost all Nvidia Quadro and GeForce cards (except the GTX 10xx series) will work with the proper drivers. I currently have a Quadro K1200 in my Mac Pro.